# I have a makefile that should generate an output file from a set of files. make -icpc=cc sort of runs but the file is not generated

Tags: gcc, makefile, linker, cc, icc

Basically I want to use GNU compiler instead of Intel.

Output of the makefile has the following:

# environment
   ISL_ROOT = /opt/shared/sw/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/isl/0.14-rhel6
   ...
   ...
    ...
    # default
    .VARIABLES :=
    # environment
    icc = CC
    # environment
    CVS_RSH = ssh

Here is part of the makefile:

```
-include ../makefile.init

RM := rm -rf

# All of the sources participating in the build are defined here
-include sources.mk
-include oed/subdir.mk
-include objects/subdir.mk
-include subdir.mk
-include objects.mk

ifneq ($(MAKECMDGOALS),clean)
ifneq ($(strip $(CC_DEPS)),)
-include $(CC_DEPS)
..
..
```

Any help is appreciated..

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: You've been here long enough to know that we can't diagnose errors by magic. The makefile fragment you posted tells us only that your build system is complicated. How different is it from the last version that worked?

Comment: I built it sometime back. But this is the first time I'm trying to build it after a few years. Sorry about the ambiguity. I should have asked a different question.
I run makefile this way make -icc="cc" and it throws the error:  
make: invalid option -- 'c'
make: invalid option -- 'c'
make: invalid option -- '='
make: invalid option -- 'c'
make: invalid option -- 'c'

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43528646/make-error-i-want-the-make-file-to-use-gcc-compiler-flags-but-originally-it-use                     I can't close this question so I made a new thread. Thx !